# Зачем нам разные способы сериализации

Tags: c#, serialize

Зачем сделали разные способы сохранения сериализированных данных?
Например зачем нам сериализация в формате XML или SOAP или Бинарная сериализация. Если можно конкретно и с примерами

Comment: Вот! Я об этом все время говорю! Зачем нам эти разные языки, разные компьютеры, разные проекции Земли? Всего надо по одному.

Comment: @Igor а еще люди разные, всех надо сделать одинаковыми!

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов На это я даже не надеюсь, но рад, что нашел здесь единомышленника.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Гитлер одобряет.

Comment: @Suvitruf как быстро его тут поминать-то начали, но фашизм это про другое.

Comment: Ого, спасибо за конструктив

Answer (score 3):

Конечно можно  Разная сериализация нужна для сохранения/передачи/обработки данных в разных форматах для разных систем.

1. Например вы работаете с такой базой данных которая поддерживает
   поиск по XML или это родной формат базы данных/колонки так что вам
   удобно сохранять в XML потому что вы сможете прямо в запросе к БД
   выбрать нужные вам данные.
2. Или вы работаете с сервисами которые понимают SOAP и вам надо объект
   передать "на ту сторону", выбор ясен.
3. Вы сохраняете файл? Или у вас Azure в котором вы храните двоичные
   данные или может вы их передаёте по TCP - вам понадобится бинарная
   сериализация.

Ну вот как-то так. Надеюсь помог.  Если нет, то пить чай с капитаном очевидностью.

Comment: Не используйте смайлики - они отображаются не у всех, вместо них, например на Win7, отображается тофу

Comment: @Андрей пора обновляться  [windows lifecycle fact sheet](https://support.microsoft.com/be-by/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet)

Comment: @pvkovalev, на рабочем ПК не мне выбирать ОС, ну и не забывайте про прочих линуксоидов

Comment: @Андрей не обижайтесь, я пошутил. На линаксе кстати нормально смотрится - не так красочно, но суть ясна : https://imgur.com/AUWXSD2 оффтоп конечно, но это я так (смайлик ->  )

Comment: @pvkovalev, линуксов целый зоопарк и вы не можете гарантировать что будет работать у всех, ну и есть пользователи других ОС

Comment: @pvkovalev почитайте [что думает сообщество по поводу смайликов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=смайлик)